# confusion about importing modules in python

Tags: python, import

I just read at least 2 ways to import .py modules in python.  Suppose, I have this directory structure:

```
/foo/bar/mymodule/a.py
/foo/bar/b.py
```

And I have `/foo/bar` in PYTHONPATH, and say I have `def a123():` in a.py and `def b123()`: in b.py respectively.

If I understand I can do..

```
from mymodule import a (suppose I have __init__.py in the directory)

from b import *
```

in order to call `a123()` and `b123()`.

What are the pros and cons of each of these two ways of declaring modules in Python, and when should I use one but not the other?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all module code in one file, put into the top level directory. If you have several files, make a package.

Comment: It's also very common to just put all the .py files into a single directory giving them the ability to import each other as needed. This also eliminates the need to modify PYTHONPATH.